# Eloquent/PHP range (from/to)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For example, my database structure is:

```
+------------+----------+
| Range from | Range To |
+------------+----------+
|        100 |      200 |
|        220 |      250 |
|        500 |      600 |
|        620 |      700 |
+------------+----------+
```

I need to check the existence of number 500. That should return true because there is a row 500-600. Also 660 should return true because there is a row 620-700.

How can I query this with Eloquent efficiently or can I only do this with native PHP? I want to avoid using loops but I don't know if that's possible.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with loops? First and foremost, you want a query with a WHERE condition that checks if your search value is between the from and to value ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all ranges that exists and count the result :

```
$value = 660;
$rangeExist = ModelName::where('range_from', '<=', $value)
                    ->where('range_to', '>=', $value)
                    ->exists();
if ($rangeExist) {
    // range exist.
}
```

And this code will work even for the case of 500 :)

Comment: You have a typo error: "if (rangeExist)" -> "if ($rangeExist)".

Comment: @jjj happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$value = 500;
$model = Model::where('from', '<', $value)->where('to', '>', $value)->count();
if ($model > 0) {
    // It does exist.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
$result = Model::where('range_from', '<=', $value)
               ->where('range_to', '>=', $value)
               ->count() > 0;
```

Comment: This will not work, it should be `range_from < $value` or `<=` (depends on what exactly OP wants). So, `from` should be less than value, but not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple `where` conditional methods with `exists` method call on your RangeModel Eloquent class.

```
$value = 500;
$existsInRange = RangeModel::where('from', '<=', value)
    ->where('to', '>=', $value)
    ->exists();
```

Take a note, `count` method will have a performance overhead.

UPD: Added `=` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get records with simple `where`.

```
$value = 600;

$count = DB::table('table_name')
            ->where('from','<',$value)
            ->where('to','>',$value)
            ->count();
```

Now,

```
if($count==0){
    // Out of Range
}else{
    // In range
}
```

Hope you understand.